# Python: xPath Click on the fly created element

Tags: python, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I'm playing around with Python and webdriver and I'm using the below code.

I'm trying to click the 'View all' option to list all the products on the page, I can click the down arrow which displays the options available but I can't click the 'View all' option, anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

It just says it can't find the second element.

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://www.boots.ie/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/SearchDisplay?categoryId=&storeId=11353&catalogId=28502&langId=-1&sType=SimpleSearch&resultCatEntryType=2&showResultsPage=true&searchSource=Q&pageView=&beginIndex=0&pageSize=24&manufacturer=lynx&isA2ZBrand=Y')

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'select_order')]/table")
element.click()
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'select_order')]/div[contains(@class, 'dijitSearchResultSelectSizeLabel')]")
element.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `wait.until` statement like this:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

# Create wait element to be used later
# 10 represents the amount of seconds to wait before throwing TimeoutException
wait = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

driver.get('http://www.boots.ie/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/SearchDisplay?categoryId=&storeId=11353&catalogId=28502&langId=-1&sType=SimpleSearch&resultCatEntryType=2&showResultsPage=true&searchSource=Q&pageView=&beginIndex=0&pageSize=24&manufacturer=lynx&isA2ZBrand=Y')

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'select_order')]/table")
element.click()

# Wait for element to pop up
wait.until(lambda driver: driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class, 'select_order')]/div[contains(@class, 'dijitSearchResultSelectSizeLabel')]'))

# Element popped up, now select & click it
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'select_order')]/div[contains(@class, 'dijitSearchResultSelectSizeLabel')]")
element.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

To click on the `View all` option to list all the products on the page, once you click the down arrow which displays the options available, next you can use the `id` of the element to click on it as follows:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id("dijit_MenuItem_1_text")
element.click()
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: Comes up with `Error: Unable to locate element: dijit_MenuItem_1_text`.